# Looking for a 64bit PDF highlighter package for large PDF files

Tags: pdf

I am trying to find what I thought would be one of the most simple pieces of code there are: a batch PDF keyword highlighter.

I found a few commercial 32-bit tools online which just crash; they just can't handle a 127 page 2D architect PDF file. I have an i5 8600K with 16 Gb of RAM.

All I wanted to do is highlight a keyword.

I have cancelled my Acrobat DC subscription because it is only 32-bits.

Please point me in the right free or paid direction that works for large PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have finally found a PDF editor for you estimators out there who are tired of downloading OCR apps when what you need is a redactor with color fill opacity highlighting capabilities.

Nitro Pro

This isn't advertising.

If you are trying to load high resolution 2D architect prints and find all occurrences of your specific TRADE keyword, this is it. Hands down.

Example:

1. Search and Redact all occurrences of keyword PAINT. The app
   highlights them all.
2. Next, DO NOT CLICK redact and instead, click Save As to save the
   file as a different copy.
3. Because you didn't proceed with the final redact, the app with just
   highlight all occurrences of the word PAINT in this example and that
   is all.